# Setting tagger to use CLAWS7 rather than default nltk.pos_tag

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

How can I set my tagger to use the CLAWS7 tagset? I havn't found a way of importing it, and the sense I get is that the nltk.pos_tag function cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The nltk's `pos_tag` function just loads and uses a particular saved tagger, so indeed it cannot be changed. But it's not very hard to train your own tagger, which you can then use. You just need a large corpus tagged with the CLAWS7 tagset, and time to wait out the training. [Chapter 5](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) in the NLTK book walks you through the process of creating a tagger.